# nan float identity compares False, but nans in tuples compare True

Tags: python, reference, comparison

Can someone explain how the following is possible? I tried it in Python 2 and 3, and got the same result. Shouldn't the `nan`s always compare not equal? Or, if it's comparing pointers, shouldn't the pointers always compare equal? What's going on?

```
>>> n = float('nan')
>>> n == n
False
>>> (n,) == (n,)
True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `n == n`, it uses the compare method of float number.

For `(n,) == (n,)`, it calls the compare method of tuple,

```
/* Search for the first index where items are different.
 * Note that because tuples are immutable, it's safe to reuse
 * vlen and wlen across the comparison calls.
 */
for (i = 0; i < vlen && i < wlen; i++) {
    int k = PyObject_RichCompareBool(vt->ob_item[i],
                                     wt->ob_item[i], Py_EQ);
    if (k < 0)
        return NULL;
    if (!k)
        break;
}
```

then it calls the compare method of *object*. It returns true immediately if two objects are the same.

```
/* Quick result when objects are the same.
   Guarantees that identity implies equality. */
if (v == w) {
    if (op == Py_EQ)
        return 1;
    else if (op == Py_NE)
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't realize that `==` doesn't call `PyObject_RichCompareBool`.